# Direct limit of sequences induced by fusing together copies of $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, group-theory, abelian-groups, limits-colimits

Let $A=l^\infty(\mathbb Z,\mathbb Z)$ be the abelian group of bounded sequences $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$. Define a homomorphism $f\colon A\to A$ by
$$f(a)(n)=a(2n)+a(2n+1),$$
for $a\in A$ and $n\in\mathbb Z$.

Consider the directed system
$$A\xrightarrow{f}A\xrightarrow{f}A\xrightarrow{f}...$$

**Question:** What is the direct limit of this system?

*Thoughts:* The map $f$ is induced by "fusing together" two the $(2n)$-th copy of $\mathbb Z$ and the $(2n+1)$-th copy, i.e. $f$ is a direct sum of the homomorphisms
$$A\supseteq\mathbb Z_{(2n)}\oplus\mathbb Z_{(2n+1)}\to\mathbb Z_{(n)}\subseteq A,$$
$$(x,y)\mapsto x+y,$$
where a subscript in parentheses denotes the index of a copy of $\mathbb Z$ in $A$. In particular, $\underbrace{f\circ f\circ\ldots\circ f}_{k\text{ times}}$ is a surjective map for any $k$. So I'm tempted to think that the direct limit is isomorphic to $A$, but I don't see a natural way to write down elements of the direct limit.

Comment: I don't see any reason to expect the direct limit to have a simpler description.  You could describe it as the quotient of $A$ by $\bigcup_n \ker(f^n)$.